# Darboux coordinates on projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, projective-space, symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds

I am trying to perform some computations in local coordinates on $\Bbb P ^n \Bbb C$ seen as a symplectic manifold, in order to get a better feeling of some facts. While I do know the coefficients of the symplectic form in the usual charts (where one projective coordinate is $1$), they do not lend themselves easily to the types of calculations that I need to do, which would be far simpler in Darboux coordinates. Consequently, does anyone know whether one can explicitly exhibit Darboux coordinates on $\Bbb P ^n \Bbb C$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What exactly do you mean by «whether one can get one's hands on...»?

Comment: The theorem of Darboux means that, provided you are only using the symplectic structure, you can always assume locally that you are on the standard symplectic $\mathbb R^{2n}$. Explicitly obtaining charts which take the symplectic form to standard form depends on solving differential equations and in general is impossible to do.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Yes, it was badly formulated, I've reformulated it now. I'd like to obtain explicit formulae for Darboux charts. I know that it's not easy, but I was hoping that since $\Bbb P ^n \Bbb C$ is one of the most studied simpler manifolds, maybe...

Comment: But **why** do you want these charts? When you have them, any local computation that you will do will be exactly the same as the corresponding computation in $\mathbb R^{2n}$!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: No, not quite: I am playing with some connections and I was interested in calculating their Christoffel coefficients.

Comment: Ah. Then you are not seeing the projective space as a symplectic manifold :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: ??? Of course I do, there are for instance symplectic connections, and not only that.

Comment: *Anything* that depends only on the symplectic structure can be treated locally as if you had $\mathbb R^{2n}$. It is **extra** structure on top of the symplectic structure that cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ["Hamiltonian manifolds and moment maps"](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/berline/cours-Fudan.pdf) by Nicole Berline and Michèle Vergne (chapter 2.3, page 19), or to the [lectures notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/karshon/grad/2009-10/2010-02-10.pdf) by Yael Karshon (page 1), Darboux coordinate patches can be obtained as follows:

- let $U = \{ [z_0 : \dots : z_n] \in \Bbb P ^n \Bbb C \mid z_0 \ne 0 \}$, as usual
- let $B = \{ (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) \in \Bbb R ^{2n} \mid x_1^2 + \dots x_n^2 + y_1^2 + \dots + y_n^2 < 1 \}$ (the open ball of radius $1$ and center $0$)
- define the parametrization $\varphi : B \to U$  by

$$\varphi (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) = \left[\sqrt{1 - x_1^2 - \dots - x_n^2 - y_1^2 - \dots - y_n^2} : x_1 + y_1 {\rm i} : \dots : x_n + y_n {\rm i} \right]$$

Similar formulae, but more annoying to write, can be produced for the other charts given by $z_i \ne 0$, for every $i = 1, \dots, n$.